# What is the best approach to handle folder paths in an API where the client and server are on different machines?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

In one of the endpoints in my API, it took a folder (to do some instructions to files inside it), when I test it in the same machine it work fine because the folder in the same machine as the API, but when I want to test it from another machine how I suppose to send folder? because if I just send folder path the API will search for the path in the server machine, the API is deployed in a server with Apache, I can access it from another machine and all endpoints work fine.

Comment: please provide code and expected results